# What does an asterisk mean in git blame for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, blame

Can someone please tell what '*' means on git blame annotation in Intellij IDEA?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated by the [official source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/investigate-changes.html#annotate_blame)

> Annotations for lines modified in the current revision, are marked with bold type and an asterisk.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I did read official source quickly, but me no speak english, so I thought 'asterisk' was that cartoon fella

Comment: @Ruslan ahah that would be `Asterix` ;)

Comment: The official source is not enough, this should be in the hover.

Answer (score 14):

The documentation says:

> Annotations for lines modified in the current revision, are marked with bold type and an asterisk.

But I think it is important to clarify that this refers to lines modified in the current revision **of the file**, not the current revision of the repository.

I think a clearer way to phrase this would be:

> Annotations for **the most recently changed lines in the file** are marked with bold type and an asterisk.

Comment: your sentence should be the correct answer here, makes much more sense than the official source